# Rotate an image at -90 degree on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, header, rotation

I want to let my image rotate at -90 degree on page scroll and stick with that -90 until I reach the bottom of my website. But if I go up again and reach the top it should rotate back to normal (0 degree).

Comment: Hello. We will help you without any problems, just share your code (minimal reproducible example), pls.

Comment: I'd suggest using a 'scroll' eventListener. It's not very performant, since it will trigger the event on each scroll, but it should get your job done. And if there isn't a lot of JS going on, you should be fine with this.
Then you check the distance to top, and if it is >100 (pixels) or so, remove css class. If however <100 you add the class again. (or the other way around)
So then you don't have to rotate via JS, but you can use CSS Transitions on a CSS Transform.

Comment: [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/centMsn/pen/wvgzVxp) Is that what You want to achive? (definitely needs to be improved - throttling can be useful)

Comment: @Centmsn I'd argue that you'd get some more freedom, if you add a class instead, since you can then adjust multiple transitions without touching your JS.
( https://codepen.io/Frizzant/pen/yLgamWw )

Comment: @Frizzant That is correct. They only goal of this example is to illustrate the solution to the author. In the end, the task is achieved :)

Comment: @Centmsn thanks for your really helpful answer! Thats exactly what I wanted to achieve. Now I just need to create a little bit more space to the top, because when the logo is rotating, the top of it is cut of. So we need to say: if the logo is rotating, then add a top margin of 20px.

Really appreciate your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is needed solution, but it works:

**HTML**

```
<img id="the_image" src="./smile.png">
```

**CSS**

```
#the_image {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

**JS**

```
//get window height
const b_height = document.querySelector("body").offsetHeight;
//get the image
const image = document.getElementById("the_image");
//set maximum rotation value
const maxRotate = -90;
//add listenet on scroll
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
  //calculating the rotation value
  let rotation = (window.scrollY / (b_height - window.innerHeight)) * maxRotate;
  rotation = rotation < maxRotate ? maxRotate : rotation;
  //use the value you get
  image.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
});
```